# Sum Numbers inside and outside brackets and create arrow based on values in VBA or Excel

Tags: vba, excel, if-statement

The question I have has two parts and I don't mind using "simple" Excel or VBA.

I basically have two columns as follows

```
    Col1     Col2
A                  
B  20(7)     4(4)
C   4(3)     9(3)
```

I want row A to sum the numbers outside the brackets with each other and the numbers within the brackets with each other. The result would be as follows.

```
    Col1     Col2
A  24(10)   13(7)          
B  20(7)     4(4)
C   4(3)     9(3)
```

So that's the first part of the question and I don't mind if this is done in Excel or VBA.

Part two of the question is creating arrows based on whether Col1 is an increase or decrease from Col2. For instance I would want an arrow pointing upward for Col1 Row A printed next to Col2 as the number has increased. I would then want another arrow pointing upward for row B and an arrow pointing downard for C to indicate a decrease. Once again Excel or VBA is fine however I would have thought this would be easier to achieve in VBA as I don't want to have to manually do this every time but instead click a command button for an arrow to appear.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: What determines if Col1 is an increase versus Col2? The difference between the numbers on the inside, the outside or something else?  For part 1 you could use logic such as in cell A1 (assuming data is in A2:B3)  =LEFT(A2,LEN(A2)-FIND("(",A2,1))+SUBSTITUTE(LEFT(A3,LEN(A3)-FIND("(",A3,1)),"(","")&"("&SUBSTITUTE(RIGHT(A2,LEN(A2)-FIND("(",A2,1)),")","")+SUBSTITUTE(RIGHT(A3,LEN(A3)-FIND("(",A3,1)),")","")&")"

Comment: An increase arrow would be when the outside number in Col1 is bigger than the outside number in Col2. Sorry, I should have made that more clear. I'll give that Excel formula a try now for part 1. Thanks

Comment: @QHarr when using the above formua I get an error at the second "FIND" function. In my code I am using data between C24:C25 and inputting in C23

Comment: Is your data as posted above and with formulas in A1:B1 and values in A2:B3?

Comment: You have two columns in your posting. Can you post an image of your data?

Comment: Oh don't worry! I must have copied it in wrong. You answer below is perfect! Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok.

Assuming data is in A2:B3.

Part 1:

In Cell A1

```
=LEFT(A2,LEN(A2)-FIND("(",A2,1))+SUBSTITUTE(LEFT(A3,LEN(A3)-FIND("(",A3,1)),"(","")&"("&SUBSTITUTE(RIGHT(A2,LEN(A2)-FIND("(",A2,1)),")","")+SUBSTITUTE(RIGHT(A3,LEN(A3)-FIND("(",A3,1)),")","")&")"
```

In Cell B1

```
=SUBSTITUTE(LEFT(B2,LEN(B2)-FIND("(",B3,1)),"(","")+SUBSTITUTE(LEFT(B3,LEN(B3)-FIND("(",B3,1)),"(","")&"("&SUBSTITUTE(RIGHT(B2,LEN(B2)-FIND("(",B2,1)),")","")+SUBSTITUTE(RIGHT(B3,LEN(B3)-FIND("(",B3,1)),")","")&")"
```

Part 2:

Cell C2 enter

```
=LEFT(A2,LEN(A2)-FIND("(",A2,1))+SUBSTITUTE(LEFT(A3,LEN(A3)-FIND("(",A3,1)),"(","")-(SUBSTITUTE(LEFT(B2,LEN(B2)-FIND("(",B3,1)),"(","")+SUBSTITUTE(LEFT(B3,LEN(B3)-FIND("(",B3,1)),"(",""))
```

Then in home tab set Font to white so value is not visible
Then in home apply formatting to the cell -> conditional formatting use icon sets -> directional

Repeat these steps for additional cells as required.